# Maven Jena schemagen: error while creating in a specific package

Tags: java, maven, jena

I'm not understanding the configuration of the maven plugin(s) after crawling around several hours.
There are two ways of configuring the schemagen as Google told me:

The first one ([see here](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/tools/schemagen.html))

```
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0</version>
        <executions>
           <execution>
              <phase>generate-sources</phase>
              <goals>
                 <goal>java</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                 <mainClass>jena.schemagen</mainClass>
                 <commandlineArgs>
                    --inference \
                    -ontology \
                    -i ${basedir}/src/main/resources/ontology/owl_file.owl \
                    --package com.company.service.domain.ontology \
                    -o ${basedir}/src/main/java/ \
                    -n Vocabulary
                 </commandlineArgs>
              </configuration>
           </execution>
        </executions>
     </plugin>
```

This approach creates the `Vocabulary` class correctly, but with the java-default package. I tried it with several styles for the arg `--package` and the `-o`, but nothing of the changes moves the generated vocabulary into the desired package.

The [second one](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/tools/schemagen-maven.html) isn't even working. It throws an exception (NULL Pointer) or does simply nothing and "skips" the goal:

```
       <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.jena</groupId>
        <artifactId>jena-maven-tools</artifactId>
        <version>${jenaVersion}</version>
        <configuration>
           <fileOptions>
              <fileOption>
                 <includes>
                    <include>src/main/resources/ontology/ont-file.owl</include>
                    <ontology>true</ontology>
                 </includes>
                 <source>
                    <input>src/main/resources/ontology/ont-file.owl</input>
                 </source>
                 <className>FancyOntologyName</className>
                 <package-name>com.company.service.domain.ontology</package-name>
              </fileOption>
           </fileOptions>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
           <execution>
              <id>schemagen</id>
              <goals>
                 <goal>translate</goal>
              </goals>
           </execution>
        </executions>
     </plugin>
```

What I want to achieve: The generated java class should be placed after generating in the desired java package, because I reference to it in the coding and need it for mapping/assertion reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok folks, I found and corrected the error.

After all the second one isn't working, but I made it with the first attempt:

```
      <commandlineArgs>
                --inference \
                --ontology \
                -i ${basedir}/src/main/resources/ontology/ont-file.owl \
                -o "${basedir}/src/main/java/" \
                --package ${mainPackage}.domain.ontology \
                -n Vocabulary
       </commandlineArgs>
```

What I've fixed:

- The args `inference`, `ontology` and `package` got two times `-` inside. Wasn't as obvious to me (unfortunately).
- The `-o` option doesn't need the full path! If you set the package, `schemagen` will put it correctly in the classpath.
- If you provider the `--package` then it will come to the effect mentioned in the last point.

Happy Jena-Schemagen-ning!